# Como generar un parse, para leer un xml y mostrarlo en un listview con soap

Tags: android, array, android-asynctask

Buenas tardes

Estoy en un desarrollo de una app que consume webservices, el punto es que el me manda un metodo menu que es un xml, lo necesito leer y mostrarlo como menu en mi app, yo estoy buscando mostrarlo en un listview, pero no se como hacer el parse, me podrian ayudar a explicarme... actualmente ya tengo mi conexion al webservices y ya me trae los datos, ya lo estaba haciendo de otra manera pero cuando termina el metodo del background no pasa al execute para que llene mi listview.. me ayudan

codigo webservices, este codigo lo tengo en una class llamada webservices(invocar)

```
 public static ArrayList Menu() {

        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","Menu");
        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        ArrayList MenuArray = new ArrayList();
        //ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/Menu", envelope);
            String ss=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            // Get the response
            // SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            // SoapObject obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(0);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject obj2 =(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(1);

            SoapObject obj3 =(SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(0);

            for(int i=0; i<obj3.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                SoapObject obj4 =(SoapObject) obj3.getProperty(i);
                int id= Integer.parseInt(obj4.getProperty("Id").toString());
                String Descripcion = obj4.getProperty("Descripcion").toString();
                MenuArray.add(i,Descripcion);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Return booleam to calling object
        //return loginStatus;

        return MenuArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38738/discussion-between-elenasys-and-hugo-rodriguez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este sería el Asynctask , el return de `doInBackground()` no debe ser nulo, y no es necesario el `onProgressUpdate()`:

```
private class AsyncCallWSMenu extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {



        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params)         {
            MenuArrayList=webService.Menu();

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        //Make Progress Bar visible
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog=new ProgressDialog(menu.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

    /*   @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }*/

        //Once WebService returns response
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
            if (!MenuArrayList.isEmpty()){
                arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, MenuArrayList);
                list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```